# Where is `dart:uri` now?

Tags: uri, dart

I want to call `decodeUrl(...)` and I was doing it as:

```
import "dart:uri";

main() {
    decodeUrl("str");
}
```

But now with the latest Dart-SDK, it reports:

```
Do not know how to load 'dart:uri'
import 'dart:uri';
^
```

Seems it has been removed from the SDK. I searched a lot but still don't know where is it now. How to use the `decodeUrl(...)` with latest SDK now?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this post to the Dart announcement list](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/announce/uri/announce/pHyoawHOhU0/MKTAnGlp9S0J), `dart:uri` has been replaced with the core [Uri](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_core/Uri.html) class.

Your code translates to:

```
main() {
  decodeUrl("str");
}
```

Though it might be more instructive to write `print(Uri.decodeFull("str%20here"));`.

Answer (score 4):

From Dart announcements of new releases, breaking changes, and other important news.

**Library dart:uri removed and class Uri added to core.**

The library dart:uri has been removed.

**What changed?**

The library dart:uri has been removed.

The class `Uri` is now in the `core library`. The `encodeUriComponent`, `enocdeUri`, `decodeUriComponent`, `decodeUri` top level functions from `dart:uri` has been moved to static methods `Uri.encodeComponent`, `Uri.enocdeFull`, `Uri.decodeComponent`, `Uri.decodeFull`.

The constructor `Uri.fromComponents` has been renamed to just `Uri` and the previous `Uri` constructor taking a URI string is no longer available but have to be replaced with a call to the static method Uri.parse.

Finally the handling of space to plus and plus to space encodeing/decoding has been removed from `Uri.encodeComponent` and `Uri.decodeComponent`. To get this encoding/decoding use the added static methods `Uri.encodeQueryComponent` and `Uri.decodeQueryComponent`.

Besides this the Uri class have additional features. See the change and the dartdoc for more information.

The dartdoc for the `Uri` class will be improved in the next couple of days.

**Who is affected?**

Users of dart:uri.

**How do I update my code?**

Change the use of `new Uri(...)` to `Uri.parse(...)`

Change the use of new `Uri.fromComponents(...)` to `new Uri(...)`

Change calls of `encodeUriComponent`, `enocdeUri`, `decodeUriComponent`, `decodeUri` to calls to `Uri.encodeComponent`, `Uri.enocdeFull`, `Uri.decodeComponent`, `Uri.decodeFull`.

Finally check of you use the fact that `encodeUriComponent` and `decodeUriComponent` changed space to plus and plus to space. If so use `Uri.encodeQueryComponent` and `Uri.decodeQueryComponent` instead of `Uri.encodeComponent` and `Uri.decodeComponent`

Comment: Very good! Where did you find the information? Could you show me a url?

Comment: Mailing list: [announce@dartlang.org](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/announce). Post: [BREAKING CHANGE: Library dart:uri removed and class Uri added to core](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/announce/pHyoawHOhU0)